# How do I insert data in selective columns using PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table on Redshift, to which I want to insert some data using pyspark dataframe. 
The redshift table has schema:

```
CREATE TABLE admin.audit_of_all_tables
(
    wh_table_name varchar,
    wh_schema_name varchar,
    wh_population_method integer,
    wh_audit_date timestamp without time,
    wh_percent_change numeric(15,5),
    wh_s3_path varchar
)
DISTSTYLE AUTO;
```

In my dataframe, I want to keep values for only the first 4 columns and write that dataframe's data to this table. 
My dataframe is something like this:
[image]

Now, I want to do `df.write.format` to my table on Redshift, but I need to somehow specify that I want to insert data to only the first four columns and pass no value for the last 2 columns (keeping them null by default).
Any idea how to specify this using `dataframe.write.format` (or any method).
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html) to select the first four columns plus two additional columns with `null` that have been [cast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#cast) to the required type:

```python
df2 = df.selectExpr("table_name as wh_table_name",
    "schema_name as wh_schema_name",
    "population_method as wh_population_method",
    "audit_date as wh_audit_date",
    "cast(null as double) as wh_percent_change",
    "cast(null as string) as wh_s3_path")

df2.write....
```